# Doctrine два раза insert'ит в базу

Tags: doctrine2

У меня есть сущность. Я делаю persist, flush, а затем мне приходят новые данные и я тут же опять делаю persist и flush. Однако doctrin'а считает что это всё ещё новая запись и вместо сохранения я получаю ошибку валидации на уникальные поля. Как это побороть?

```
$obj1 = new Test();
$obj1->setName('test');
$em->persist($obj1);
$em->flush();
$obj2 = new Test2();
$obj2->setObj1Id($obj1->getId());
$em->persist($obj2);
$obj1->setObj($obj2);
$em->persist($obj1);
$em->flush();
```

Вот, когда второй раз делаешь flush, то в obj1 возникает ошибка неуникального name, т.к первый раз его в бд вставил, а второй раз доктрина опять считает что это insert и пытается опять вставить данные вместо того чтобы просто обновить поле через сеттер setObj

Comment: merge нужно делать. Т.е. связать сущность с уже существующей..

Comment: Добавьте код и описания при каких условиях приходят новые данные.

Answer (score 0):

По идеи вот так должно работать . Но судя по коду у вас похоже отношение один ко многим и если я прав реализуется оно не так.

```
$obj1 = new Test();
$obj1->setName('test');
$em->persist($obj1);
$em->flush();
$em->clear();

$obj2 = new Test2();
$obj2->setObj1Id($obj1->getId());
$em->persist($obj2);
$obj1->setObj($obj2);
$em->persist($obj1);
$em->flush();
```